# How to Populate value in Text Field from Picklist in Salesforce?

Tags: trigger, workflow

I want to populate values in TEXT field automatically while selecting values from picklist. I need to do this task using :

1. Formula Field
2. Workflows
3. Triggers

Answer (score 3):

You can do this using easily using any of the above three methods.

1. **Formula**
   Create formula field and do `TEXT(Picklist__c)`
2. **Workflow** Crate a Wf created and Edited and on Field Update select your text field and then update this `TEXT(Picklist__c)`
3. **Trigger** Create a before insert, before update trigger and do simply

   for(Object a : trigger.new)
          a.YourTextField__c = a.Picklist__c;

Comment: I've created a Field Update with formula using this formula: (TEXT(PicklistWorkflow__c) ) || But not getting desired update.

Comment: `TEXT(PicklistWorkflow__c)` use only this and what are you not getting. Provide more detail @NitinGupta

Comment: I've done using this TEXT(PicklistWorkflow__c) but still not able to populate value in text field

Comment: Can you provide me whole logic?

Comment: @NitinGupta did you created the Formula field and check there API name is correct and make sure you have value selected in original picklist. And add some screenshot of your record.

Answer (score -1):

@Nitin we achieve this by below mentioned approach :

1. To Create a formula field :For this Formula : Create formula field with formula : "PicklistFieldName__c" rather than using TEXT() function. It is working for me.
2. By writing a flow
3. By Trigger

Comment: This is largely the same as the existing answer, but with less information. In particular, the second and third points here are useless tautologies (i.e. "to do X, you need to do X")